# Determine the interval for convergence for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (\sqrt{x})^n $

Tags: calculus, power-series

I have an assignment for class - and this one is completely bugging me out.

I need to find the interval $I$, in which 
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (\sqrt{x})^n $ converges.

The only thing that pops to my mind would be - if the series converged in I=]0;1[. In that way the number would becombe smaller and smaller - and eventually 0.

I do however assume this is wrong - as a later task, in the same assignment, implies that I should show that the series is monotonically increasing in the interval $I$.

Can anybody help me? I feel like this is not very hard; but I've complete forgotten how to do this.

Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the $nth$ root test,  you have $\sum a_n$ converges when $a_n^{\frac 1 n}<1$.

Applying that,  you need $\sqrt x<1$,  Normally the radius would be around $0$, but since your function isn't defined below 0, you have it converges in $[0,1)$.  All that's left is to check the endpoint, and it clearly diverges at $x=1$

Edit: To address your confusion, it converges for any $x\in [0,1)$.  But it converges to a BIGGER number for bigger $x's$,  and to show that, all you need is that $\sqrt x$ is monotonically increasing in your interval

Edit 2:  Oh, and of course, $y^n$ is monotonically increasing also for each $n$

Comment: 1 year later, I found these great answers. Thank you so much for explaining so thoroughly,

Comment: @MathyFoxy My pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

Try the root test.

Or the ratio test
(using
$\frac{(\sqrt{x})^{n+1}}{(\sqrt{x})^{n}}
=\sqrt{x}
$).